# Set-ItemProperty for http removes existing bindings for website in IIS

Tags: powershell, web, iis

One of my application (say `app1`) running under website in IIS created `https` binding during deployment. However when another application (say `app2`) under same website deployed recently via power shell script, it removed previously added `https` binding and broke `app1`.

When I looked into deployment script of `app2`, I realized there is a function to check if binding already exist - if yes, simply call `Set-ItemProperty` to update that binding or else create the one. This idea looks fine to me - basically it says create binding specific to application or update if already existing. But am not sure, why `Set-ItemProperty` for `http` removed `https` binding (in fact all others as well like `net.tcp`, `net.pipe` etc)

Below is `function` from that deployment script.

```
Import-Module -Name WebAdministration
    function SetBindingsIIS
    {
    param
    (
       [Parameter(Mandatory)]
       [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
       [string]$WebsiteName,
       [HashTable]$protocol
    )
    $Status=$null
    $GetProtocolName= $protocol["Protocol"]
    $BindingsCollection=Get-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\Sites\$WebsiteName" -Name Bindings 
    $ProtocolExists=$BindingsCollection.Collection | Where-Object{$_.protocol -eq $GetProtocolName}
        Try
        {
            if($ProtocolExists -eq $null)
            {
                New-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\Sites\$WebsiteName -Name Bindings -Value $protocol -Force
            }
            else
            {
                Set-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\Sites\$WebsiteName" -Name Bindings -Value $protocol -Force
            }
            $Status="Success"
        }
        Catch
        {
            $ErrorMessage=$_.Exception.Message        
            $Status="Error in Add/Update bindings : $ErrorMessage"
        }

        return $Status
    }
```

**Running this function simply removes all existing bindings already configured for web site in IIS**

```
SetBindingsIIS -WebsiteName "TestMiddleTierSite" -protocol @{Protocol="http";BindingInformation=":81:"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is removing all your bindings is that it is taking whatever you pass to `$Protocol` and over-writing the `Bindings` property, which is a collection of *all* the bindings for the site.

You should use the `WebAdministration` module that ships with IIS to do this instead of the generic item cmdlets.  It contains various useful cmdlets, including `Set-WebBinding` and `New-WebBinding`.  For example:

`New-WebBinding -Name "TestMiddleTierSite" -IPAddress "*" -Port 81 -Protocol http`

Answer (score 2):

While @boxdog's answer is right and recommendable: it is possible to add a binding using *-ItemProperty and the IIS: PSDrive. Just do not use **Set**-ItemProperty, but **New**-ItemProperty to add a new property to the collection:

```
New-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -Name bindings -Value @{protocol='http'; bindingInformation='*:81:'}
```